# not getting array values from view codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

my model function is

```
    public function getUser()
{
    $this->db->select(array('customer_name','customer_address','phone_no','fax','email_id','contact_person_name','mobile_no'));     
    $this->db->from('add_customer');
    $this->db->where(array('status'=>1));
    $res = $this->db->get();
    if($res->num_rows() > 0)
    { 
        $rows = $res->result_array();
        return $rows;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

function in controller

```
public function search_customer()
{

    //$this->load->helper('url');
    $data['baseurl'] = base_url();
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $data['details'] = $this->Customer_model->getUser();
    $this->load->view('master/customer',$data);
}
```

data extracting from my view is like this

```
     <?php for($i=0;$i<count($details);$i++){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ($i+1); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details[$i]['customer_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details[$i]['customer_address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details[$i]['phone_no']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details[$i]['email_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details[$i]['contact_person_name']; ?></td>
    <?php }?>
```

and this one results in an error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: details

Filename: master/Customer.php

Line Number: 69
```

anybody please tell me why this error is getting

Comment: Can you indicate where exactly is Line Number: 69?  Also, what is in `templates/header`?

Comment: @MarcAudet I have got the answer.The field status is not there in the table is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to load your model in your controller like

```
$this->load->model('Customer_model');
```

without loading your model you con't get the details from get_user function

Comment: not exactly it is an error in the field name of my table, thanks.i don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public function getUser()
{
    $this->db->select('customer_name','customer_address','phone_no',
            'fax','email_id','contact_person_name','mobile_no');     
    $this->db->from('add_customer');
    $this->db->where('status',1);
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function search_customer()
{
    $data['baseurl'] = base_url();
    //Load the view in variable as data, but do not render 
    //($header is accessible in 'master/customer' view)
    $data['header'] = $this->load->view('templates/header','',true);
    //Be sure to load Customer_model
    $data['details'] = $this->Customer_model->getUser();
    $this->load->view('master/customer',$data);
}
```

View:

```
<?php if(count($details)): ?>
   <?php foreach($details as $detail): ?>
   <tr>
       <td><?php echo $detail->customer_name; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $detail->customer_address; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $detail->phone_no; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $detail->email_id; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $detail->contact_person_name; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try using `$data` instead of `$details` in your master/Customer.